# Is there a way to get Laravel's authenticated user ID in Lighthouse?

Tags: php, laravel, lighthouse

I am developing a Web API with Laravel, and I want to use Lighthouse to move from REST to GraphQL.
Until now, the controller has read `auth ()-> id` and set it in the user_id column of the record to be added.
How can I set user_id to `auth ()-> id` in Lighthouse?

Answer (score 1):

I solved myself. @inject directive
https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#inject